# merging duplicated colums by which row is greater than others

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-manipulation

i have list of dataframes and the dataframes have some duplicated columns. I want to merge duplicated columns which row is greater than others(some data frames have much more duplicates).

example data:

```
temp <- data.frame(seq_len(15), 5, 3)
colnames(temp) <- c("A", "A", "B")

temp$A[5]=NA
temp$A[3]=NA
temp$A[2]=NA
temp[7,2]=NA
```

```
  A     A       B
<int> <dbl>   <dbl>
  1     5       3       
  NA    5       3       
  NA    5       3       
  4     5       3       
  NA    5       3       
  6     5       3       
  7     NA      3       
  8     5       3       
  9     5       3       
 10     5       3
```

final output

```
 A     B
<int> <dbl>
  1     3
  5     3
  5     3
  5     3
  5     3
  6     3
  7     3
  8     3
  9     3   
 10     3
```

Thanks for everyone

Comment: The first value in `A` column should be 5?

Comment: the important sitution is NA observation but this too helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R approach would be to split the data frame based on similarity of columns and select row-wise maximum using `do.call` + `pmax`.

```
data.frame(sapply(split.default(temp, names(temp)), function(x) 
           do.call(pmax, c(x, na.rm = TRUE))))

#    A B
#1   5 3
#2   5 3
#3   5 3
#4   5 3
#5   5 3
#6   6 3
#7   7 3
#8   8 3
#9   9 3
#10 10 3
#11 11 3
#12 12 3
#13 13 3
#14 14 3
#15 15 3
```

Comment: Thank you man for replying quickly .i will implement original data set at morning if get some issues I will reply.